# How to operate at24c32 by smbus in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, i2c, eeprom, smbus

What if the EEPROM used is greater than 32K, such as at24c32, and the register address is 16bit? It seems that smbus only supports 8bit registers?

I can read 0xff, but the written content will return - 5, which fails.
I want to know whether the kernel only supports 8-bit registers, but not 16 bit registers?

This is my code:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define AT24C32_ADDR 0x53

__s32 i2c_smbus_access(int file, char read_write, __u8 command,
                       int size, union i2c_smbus_data* data)
{
    struct i2c_smbus_ioctl_data args;
    __s32 err;

    args.read_write = read_write;
    args.command = command;
    args.size = size;
    args.data = data;

    err = ioctl(file, I2C_SMBUS, &args);
    if (err == -1)
        err = -errno;
    return err;
}

__s32 i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(int file, __u8 command, __u8 value)
{
    union i2c_smbus_data data;
    data.byte = value;
    return i2c_smbus_access(file, I2C_SMBUS_WRITE, command,
                            I2C_SMBUS_BYTE_DATA, &data);
}

__s32 i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(int file, __u8 command)
{
    union i2c_smbus_data data;
    int err;

    err = i2c_smbus_access(file, I2C_SMBUS_READ, command,
                           I2C_SMBUS_BYTE_DATA, &data);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    return 0x0FF & data.byte;
}

static int32_t i2c_smbus_write_word_data(int file, uint8_t cmd, uint16_t value)
{
    union i2c_smbus_data data;

    data.word = value;

    return i2c_smbus_access(file, I2C_SMBUS_WRITE, cmd,
                            I2C_SMBUS_WORD_DATA, &data);
}

static int32_t i2c_smbus_read_word_data(int fd, uint8_t cmd)
{
    union i2c_smbus_data data;
    int err;

    err = i2c_smbus_access(fd, I2C_SMBUS_READ, cmd,
                           I2C_SMBUS_WORD_DATA, &data);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    return data.word;
}

int set_slave_addr(int file, int address, int force)
{
    /* With force, let the user read from/write to the registers
       even when a driver is also running */
    if (ioctl(file, force ? I2C_SLAVE_FORCE : I2C_SLAVE, address) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Error: Could not set address to 0x%02x: %s\n",
                address, strerror(errno));
        return -errno;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do.  But as far as accessing an i2c device from Linux, see if this helps: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface

Comment: @paulsm4, why? Linux kernel has a driver for that IC.

Comment: So, and what prevents you to enable at24 driver and access to it as usual file (under sysfs)?

Comment: The at24. c supports i2c drivers, but does not support smbus?

Comment: My memory chip is 32K, so the address register is 16 bits, and the kernel smbus driver only supports 8 bits.